Asphalt Shingle Maintenance. Advice on on some quick repair. Exposed Nails
How are things looking on this roof? I first noticed the exposed nail heads that have worn off caulking. My plan is to re-caulk it myself (geocell 2300) while cutting some circular tabs of asphalt shingle to cap the nail. Is this the way?
Two other questions:
1.) One nail is noticeably uplifted a bit. Should I knock it back into flush?
2.) In the pic, the third shingle on the ridge (from the bottom) looks to have been snapped off. This OK?
More images:
https://imgur.com/a/DXrNG5y


If the nail is up/pop up, I would remove it completely and move over a bit.  The nail hole will not hold the nail anymore, so just banging it back in will only last till you get down.  Replacing the shingle that is broken is best.

Got it, thanks!

You should really replace the one or two ridge shingles, one that's broken off and one that looks like it's missing. Any nails that are popping up probably missed the decking and should be moved over a bit and hammered back in. Holes should be patched with a wet patch sealer as should any exposed nail heads.

Yep.nails except at the  very ends, are normally covered by an overlapping shingle. The dark area is where one of the overlaps broke off. Ideal repair is to undo things enough to reassemble with a full-height piece there

Thanks for the comments. So is the darker black area where the exposed nails are, tar adhesive? Also, looking at the pic, I'm noticing the wear on a few of the other ridge shingles. Curious what caused that, but are these shingles still in good shape?

@Jake  The darker black area is probably the adhesive strip from the part of the shingle that's been ripped off. The wear could be from walking on them or they could have had the wear before being installed, manufacturing / shipping wear.  They are in good shape.

Ok got it, thanks!

Seems that there's a shingle missing at the end.
For that last shingle at the ridge, I like to use a roofing nail washer. Like this:

If you don't want to buy a 33sq ft pack of shingles just for that little bit, you might just want to change the exposed nails using the washers. At the ridge, it'll work.

Thanks! So this is for the final nails that have no shingle covering them, correct? Trying to figure out what that darker black line is along the nails. Is that a tar adhesive used instead of nails? I'm also trying to figure out the logic of the current install with a few exposed nails versus there being no nails elsewhere on the ridge

The tar line is how one shingle bonds to the next one above. Nails are covered by the shingle above, up to the last shingle. There, you use the roofing washers.

Appreciate the info.
